# MySQL query from Spring web application using a RowMapper implementation

Tags: mysql, spring, resultset

I´m trying to receive the result of this query:

```
    SELECT n.*, r.nombre as nom 
    FROM noticias n 
    INNER JOIN actperiodicas r 
    WHERE (n.idActPer = r.idActPer) and (n.idActPer>0) 
    UNION

    SELECT n.*, s.nombre as nom 
    FROM noticias n 
    INNER JOIN actpuntuales s 
    WHERE (n.idActPunt = s.idActPunt) and (n.idActPunt >0)
    UNION
    SELECT n.*, '-' as nom 
    FROM noticias n 
    WHERE (n.idActPer=0) and (n.idActPunt=0)
    ORDER BY fechaPublicacion DESC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

and i'm using a mapper with this code for the mapRow function (Interface RowMapper):

```
public Noticia mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

    Noticia not = new Noticia();

    not.setIdNoticia(rs.getInt("idNoticia"));
    not.setFechaPublicacion(rs.getString("fechaPublicacion"));
    not.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
    not.setTexto(rs.getString("texto"));
    not.setNomImagen(rs.getString("nomImagen"));
    not.setIdActPer(rs.getInt("idActPer"));
    not.setIdActPunt(rs.getInt("idActPunt"));

    not.setNomAct(rs.getString("nom"));

    return not;
}
```

As you might have already noticed: the 'nom' column is the name I give to the column 'nombre' from the tables 'actPuntuales' and 'actPeriodicas', and it's simply a '-' character when my 'noticias' table row needs  no name (nom).

My problem is: the value of nom correct when i execute the query using Toad por example, but when I try to receive it in my application, it always equals Null

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance for your help ;)

Comment: Is this being done from any service?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't anderstand exactly what you mean with service.

Comment: It's done from a web application, so I'm the petition is received through the http protocol..
I'm really sorry Sirsendu if i'm not answering correctly your question, i´m new to this.

Comment: Is it possible to share the Code snippet? Or can you please inform if you write System.out.println(not) before the return not; what does it print?

Comment: To be more simple,          do you have similar code used as shown below?                            Noticia noticia= (Noticia) jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{id}, new YourMapper());

Comment: Yes of course! I'm executing the query from a DAO ( it extends JdbcDaoSupport), and I'm using its getJdbcTemplate.query() function. 
Here's the code:
        List<Noticia> acp = getJdbcTemplate().query(
            query,
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Noticia>(Noticia.class)
        );
The Comment text area won't let me give a good format to the code i wrote. Sorry.

Comment: If you are using BeanPropertyRowMapper then why this code is being used? public Noticia mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException { 
.......}

Comment: You need to call the method in dao to get the result.

Comment: That is what I do, I call the method, it returns the correct set of rows, with all the values of the Noticia atributes correctly set, exepting the 'nomAct' that i shoulf receive in the column 'nom' of the resultSet.
When I print the content of 'acp' (List<Noticia>), every atribute is correct, but 'nom'. It is printed as null.

Comment: As I couldn't give a classy and working syntax for my query, I have decided to go for a brute one: I'll get a list of all the content of the table Noticias (n), and then I'll get the name of the items that do have one.